# Case when situation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

Here is the sample data set and the first command that I know how to do. I want everything else that is not listed in the command to be areatype 04. I know that I could list the three out in this simple example. However, in reality I have 35 other possibilities that needed to coded as areatype 04. Is there something that I can add to the last line of code that would say "if this then 07 but if anything else then 04"

```
  area <- c("000995","000996","000001","000005","000998","000007")
  areatype<- c("","","","","","")

  list <- data.frame(county,areatype)

  list <- list %>% mutate(areatype=case_when(area=='000995'~'07',area=='000996'~'07')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%` and specify the `TRUE` as the else option i.e. if we don't specify the `TRUE`, by default it will be replaced by `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
list %>% 
   mutate(areatype = case_when(county %in% c('000995', '000996')~'07', 
          TRUE ~ '04'))
```

NOTE: `list` is a function name i.e. avoid naming objects with function names

Answer (score 2):

In base R you can also do this with `ifelse`:

```
list$areatype <- ifelse(list$area %in% c("000995", "000996"), "07", "04")
```

---

Alternatively, if you have a lot of `area` values with sequential suffixes you could do something like:

```
match <- grepl(paste(do.call(sprintf, list("%i$", 995:996)), collapse = "|"), list$area)
list$areatype <- ifelse(match, "07", "04")
```

Where the first line will return `TRUE` for any element of `list$area` that ends with `995` or `996` and `FALSE` otherwise.